# which equations may be solved with compass and a marked ruler?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometric-construction

Ancient Greeks were not able to trisect a general angle with compass and straightedge: now we know that it is impossible, since we would need to solve a cubic equation while only linear and quadratic equations are soluble.

But Greeks also knew that if the ruler is **marked** then trisection is possible. My question: which is the set of equations which may be solved with compass and marked ruler?

Comment: I think they have to have solutions in field obtained from the rationals by a sequence of quadratic and cubic extensions. But I'm sure this is in the literature, and should be findable by Google.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145957/on-constructions-by-marked-straightedge-and-compass may be helpful to you.

Comment: Also please look at Arthur Baragar's paper, Constructions using a compass and twice-notched straightedge, Amer. Math. Monthly 109 (2002), no. 2, 151–164, MR1903152 (2003d:51015).

Comment: Have you had a look at these references?

Comment: Hi Gerry, I already noticed the question here on math.SE, but it seemed to me that it was a bit different, explaining what you could do with an instrument dividing a general angle in $2n+1$ parts. I'm going to search for the paper by Baragar

Comment: (btw, that article is available online, https://faculty.unlv.edu/baragar/papers/monthly151-164.pdf )

Comment: Had a chance yet to look at the Baragar paper?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, eventually I managed. It turned out that with a two-notched straighedge and a compass it is possible to construct points belonging to a field K that lies in a tower of fields for which the index between any two fields is 2,3,5 or 6. This means that 3rd- and 4th-degree equations can be solved and that some quintic may be solved too. Practical problems, like "which regular n-gons may be constructed?", are still open: it is known that a 23-gon cannot constructed, but nothing can still be said about a 11-gon.

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to post that as an answer (and then to accept it).

Comment: I find it a bit cheating to add my own answer, but since nobody else answered I just added it.

Comment: On the contrary, stackexchange encourages people to answer their own questions (and so do I, as it gives people practice writing things up).

Comment: @mau The question of whether the hendecagon could be constructed with marked ruler was solved affirmatively in 2014. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1904817/357390).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arthur Baragar studied the constructions where, besides the compass, a straightedge with two notches is available. He shows [in this article](https://faculty.unlv.edu/baragar/papers/monthly151-164.pdf) that with these tools it is possible to trisect an angle and to duplicate the cube, that is to construct a segment whose length is $\sqrt[3]{2}$: these constructions were essentially known to Greek mathematics already.

Baragar gave also the most general answer to the question: for a number $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} $ to be constructable with a straightedge with two notches and a compass, it must belong to a field K that lies in a tower of fields

$$\mathbb{Q} = K_0 \subset K_1 \subset K_2 \subset ... \subset K_n = K$$

for which the index $ [K_j : K_{j-1} ]$ at each step is 2, 3, 5 or 6.

All cubic and quartic equations may be solved, together with some quintic - even some not  solvable by radicals; the article states that it is an open problem whether any quintics may be solved.