# Constructing the 11-gon by splitting an angle in five

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, polygons, minimal-polynomials

In "[Angle Trisection, the Heptagon, and the Triskaidecagon](https://web.archive.org/web/20151219180208/http://apollonius.math.nthu.edu.tw/d1/ne01/jyt/linkjstor/regular/7.pdf)", published in the *American Mathematical Monthly* in March 1988, Andrew Gleason discusses what regular polygons can be constructed with compass, straightedge and angle trisector. At the end of that article he notes that the angle *p*-sectors required for a regular *n*-gon are the odd primes *p* dividing $\varphi(n)$.

For the heptagon, which only requires an angle trisector, he gives the minimal polynomial of $2\cos(2\pi/7)$
$$x^3+x^2-2x-1$$
and transforms it into the Chebyshev polynomial expression
$$7\sqrt{28}(4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta)=7$$
leading to the final identity
$$\sqrt{28}\cos\left(\frac{\cos^{-1}(1/\sqrt{28})}{3}\right)=1+6\cos(2\pi/7).$$

I am interested in the hendecagon (11 sides), which requires an angle quinsector (that splits an angle into five equal parts).

> Is there a similar transformation between the minimal polynomial for $2\cos(2\pi/11)$
>   $$x^5+x^4-4x^3-3x^2+3x+1$$
>   and the relevant Chebyshev polynomial
>   $$\cos 5\theta=16\cos^5\theta-20\cos^3\theta+5\cos\theta$$
>   and how do I find it? If I had such a transformation, I could construct an exact hendecagon with the quinsector.

I have tried Tschirnhaus transforms on the former polynomial, without success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(***Updated answer***)

While the old answer used a cubic transformation, I remembered that the general quintic can reduced to a one-parameter form (*[the Brioschi quintic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562449/)*) using only ***quadratic*** Tschirnhausen transformations. So given a solvable quintic,

$$F(x)=0$$

to transform that to the solvable DeMoivre form,

$$y^5+5my^3+5m^2y+n = 0$$

the trick is to use a *rational* Tschirnhausen of form,

$$y = \frac{x^2+ax+b}{x+c}$$

and the four parameters ($a,b,c,m$) suffice to enable the transformation. For the minimal polynomial of $x = 2\cos(2\pi/11),$

$$x^5 + x^4 - 4x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x + 1=0\tag1$$

surprisingly the transformation just involves powers of the **golden ratio** $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt5}2,$

$$y = \frac{x^2+(\phi^2/\sqrt5)x-(\phi^2/\sqrt5)}{x+\phi^2}\tag2$$

Eliminating $x$ between $(1)$ and $(2)$, after simplification, one gets the special DeMoivre quintic,

$$y^5+5\left(\frac{-7+\sqrt5}{\;10\phi^2}\right)y^3+5\left(\frac{-7+\sqrt5}{\;10\phi^2}\right)^2y+\left(\frac{-830+139\sqrt5}{\;11(\phi\sqrt5)^6}\right)=0\tag3$$

Like any DeMoivre, this has a solution in terms of **arccos**. So the roots $x$ and $y$,

$$x = 2\cos(2\pi/11)$$
$$y = \frac2{\phi}\sqrt{\frac{7-\sqrt5}{10}}\,\cos\big(z\big)$$
$$z =\frac15\arccos\left(\frac{-15+32\sqrt5}{110}\sqrt{\frac{10}{7-\sqrt5}}\right)$$

Since $x,y$ only have a quadratic relation,

$$y = \frac{x^2+(\phi^2/\sqrt5)x-(\phi^2/\sqrt5)}{x+\phi^2}$$

then one can solve for $x$ using the quadratic formula and express it in terms of $y$ without using cube roots as in the old answer.

$$\\$$

---

(***Old answer***)

The question essentially asks about transforming *solvable* equations from one form to another.

**I. Cubic**

Using just a linear transformation, the general cubic $P(x)=0$ can be transformed to the form,

$$y^3+3ay+b = 0\tag1$$

with solution,

$$y_k = 2\sqrt{-a}\;\cos\left(-\tfrac{2\pi\,k}{3}+\tfrac{1}{3}\,\arccos\big(\tfrac{-b}{2\sqrt{-a^3}}\big)\right)\tag2$$

for $k=0,1,2$. Undoing the transformation establishes a relation between the roots $x,y$.

**II. Quintic**

Similarly, an *appropriate* Tschirnhausen transformation can transform a ***solvable*** quintic $P(x)=0$ to the Demoivre form (essentially the Chebyshev polynomial mentioned by the OP),

$$y^5+5ay^3+5a^2y+b = 0\tag3$$

with analogous solution,

$$y_k = 2\sqrt{-a}\;\cos\left(-\tfrac{2\pi\,k}{5}+\tfrac{1}{5}\,\arccos\big(\tfrac{-b}{2\sqrt{-a^5}}\big)\right)\tag4$$

for all five roots $y_k$. A cubic Tschirnhausen gives us three degrees of freedom to transform a solvable quintic to Demoivre form.

**III. Transformations**

**For $p=7$:**

$$x=2\cos\big(\tfrac{2\pi}{7}\big)\tag5$$

$$\color{blue}{y=3x+1} = 2\sqrt{7}\cos\left(\tfrac{1}{3}\,\cos^{-1}\big(\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{7}}\big)\right)$$

then $x,y$ solves,

$$x^3+x^2-2x-1=0$$
$$y^3-21y-7=0$$

**For $p=11$:**

Let $\phi=\tfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ be the *golden ratio*.

$$x=2\cos\big(\tfrac{2\pi}{11}\big)\tag6$$

$$\color{blue}{y =x^3-\phi\,x^2-\tfrac{7+\sqrt{5}}{2}x+\tfrac{5+4\sqrt{5}}{5}} = 2\,\phi\sqrt{\tfrac{11}{5}}\cos\left(-\tfrac{6\pi}{5}+\tfrac{1}{5}\,\cos^{-1}\big(\tfrac{-89-25\sqrt{5}}{44\sqrt{11}}\big)\right)$$

then $x,y$ solves,

$$x^5 + x^4 - 4x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x + 1=0$$
$$y^5-5ay^3+5a^2y+b=0$$

where $a=\tfrac{11}{5}\phi^2,\;\;b=\tfrac{11(125+89\sqrt{5})}{250}\phi^5$.

Thus as you can see, the transformation (in blue) which relates the quintic roots $x,y$ is more complicated than the cubic version, but is nonetheless doable in radicals.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel: I hope the cubic relation between the quintic roots $x,y$ is enough for your question.

Comment: The construction from here is doable with the quinsector, except possibly for the transformation from y to x, which looks like it needs an angle trisector. However, if I interpret my quinsector as having six rods (0 to 5) and the trisection as using only rods 0 to 3, then it is valid. Enough for an accept.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: I considered a $7$th deg analogue in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1904957/4781).

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: This is an old post. But I realized that to transform solvable quintics to DeMoivre form, a **quadratic** but rational Tschirnhausen transformation would suffice. Hence no trisection needed as in the old answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the object is to construct a regular hendecagon, it can be done more simply without going through an angle quinsection.  Benjamin and Snyder proved the existence of a construction using a marked ruler and compasses in 2014 (BENJAMIN, ELLIOT; SNYDER, C. Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society156.3 (May 2014): 409-424.; http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004113000753 ).

The basic premises of the construction are as follows:

1. It's based on the properties of "conchoid-circle" constructions where we position the marked straightedge to paas through a fixed point $P$, with one mark on a line $l$ and the other on a circle $K$.
2. With this type of construction, we define a "signed distance" $z$.  This is the distance between $P$ and the mark on $K$, with a negative sign if that mark lies vetween $P$ and the other mark which is on $l$, a positive sign otherwise.
3. Then $z$ satisfies a sextic equation whose coefficients satisfy certain relationships called the "verging theorem".
4. The quintic equation given here for the hendecagonal cosines is converted to a sextic equation that satisfies the verging theorem by (4.1) defining $z=ux$ for some scale factor $u$, and (4.2) introducing an additional root $\eta$ with the appropriate value relative to $u$.  Then, all the geometric parameters needed to determine $l$ and $K$ may be expressed and constructed in terms of this  scale factor $u$.
5. Now to the heart of the matter.  It looks like we have to solve a seventh-degree equation for that parameter $u$. But, "a miracle occurs"  (the authors' own words); the equation for $u$ is reducuble and all we are left with is a cubic factor equation (with integer coefficients), which can be solved by an auxiliary marked ruler construction. (The "miracle" appears to be related to the Gauss sum for hendecagonal angles, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3258069/248217).)
6. So $z=ux$ has a construction with a marked ruler and compasses because it solves a sextic equation that satisfies the verging theorem,  and $u$ has such a construction as well because it is obtained from a cubic equation in $Z[u]$; and so $x=2 cos(2\pi m/11)$ has one too.
7. Now for the parameters.  For $u$, choose the one real root of $u^3+2u^2+2u+2=0$.  For the construction of $z=ux$:  $P=(0,0)$, $l$ is the line $x=-u-1$ where the length unit is the distance between the marks (conventional in this type of construction), $K$ is centeted at $(u(u-1)/2,-(u^2+3u+1)/2)$ and passes through $(-u-2,0)$.  One orientation of the ruler is along the $x$ axis, that is the "extra" root of the sextic; the other roots on $K$ with proper distance signs, see (2), give the roots for $z$.  Note that the authors do not give the formulas that way, I did some algebra of my own to get everything in terms of $u$.