# Find all points that have the same total distance to given points

Tags: geometry

I have a problem similar to that of finding the geometric median. Suppose I have $n$ fixed points $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$; what is the set of points that have the same total distance $\ell$ to these fixed points?

Is there any theory relating to this problem? Is there any chance that these points have some relationship with the geometric median?

Comment: I do not quite understand "the collection of points that have the same total distance to these points".  Could you give a small example?  Does this mean for example with two points and a stated total you get an ellipse/ellipsoid?

Comment: The smallest possible total distance will (by definition) correspond to the geometric median.

Comment: Hi Henry, thank you for your reply. I know about geometric median. However, I am not going to find the geometric median. Instead, I am going to find the all the points that the total distance between each point to the sample points  is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The set of points that have the same sum-distance to $n$ given points is called an [$n$-ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse). An example is shown below.

[image: Otherwise known as the Tschirnhaus egg curve]

These curves have almost nothing to do with the geometric median, except that the median is what the curves degenerate to as the given sum-distance decreases. Maxwell studied them, and we know a few properties: [they are polynomial plane curves of high degree](http://math.ucsd.edu/~njw/PUBLICPAPERS/kellipse_imaproc_toappear.pdf) and [they can approximate certain convex closed curves](http://renyi.mta.hu/~p_erdos/1982-18.pdf).

*I* once investigated the area enclosed by such a curve, and [the results](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879001/to-find-area-of-the-curves-that-are-extension-of-ellipse/1886982#1886982) were far from simple.