# Transforming solvable equations to the de Moivre analogues

Tags: trigonometry, algebraic-geometry, radicals, minimal-polynomials

(*This question was inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876590/).*)

> **I. Quintic**

Given a *solvable* quintic

$$F(x)=0\tag1$$

the problem is to transform it to the *de Moivre form*

$$y^5+5ay^3+5a^2y+b=0\tag2$$

using only a ***third***-degree Tschirnhausen transformation

$$y=x^3+c_1x^2+c_2x+c_3\tag3$$

Eliminating $x$ between $(1)$ and $(3)$ yields the quintic

$$y^5+d_1y^4+d_2y^3+d_3y^2+d_4y+d_5=0.\tag4$$
The three unknowns $c_i$ allow us to solve the system
$$d_1 = d_3 =0$$
$$d_2^2=5d_4$$

Its final equation turns out to be of $12$-deg, but seems to be factorable and solvable when $(1)$ is solvable. And since the quintic roots $x,y$ are related by

$$y=x^3+c_1x^2+c_2x+c_3=2\sqrt{-a}\;\cos\left(-\tfrac{2\pi\,k}{5}+\tfrac{1}{5}\,\arccos\big(\tfrac{-b}{2\sqrt{-a^5}}\big)\right)\tag5$$

then such transformations may yield unusual trigonometric identities like,

$$\color{brown}{x^3-\phi\,x^2-\tfrac{7+\sqrt{5}}{2}x+\tfrac{5+4\sqrt{5}}{5} = 2\,\phi\sqrt{\tfrac{11}{5}}\cos\left(-\tfrac{6\pi}{5}+\tfrac{1}{5}\,\cos^{-1}\big(\tfrac{-89-25\sqrt{5}}{44\sqrt{11}}\big)\right)=-4.7985\dots}$$

where $x=2\cos\big(\tfrac{2\pi}{11}\big)$ and the golden ratio $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Similar relations in radicals can be found using other quintics.

> **II. Septic**

Similarly, given the *solvable* septic
$$F(x) =0\tag6$$
we transform it to the de Moivre quintic's seventh-degree analogue
$$y^7+7ay^5+14a^2y^3+7a^3y+b=0\tag7$$
using a ***fifth***-degree Tschirnhausen 
$$y=x^5+c_1x^4+c_2x^3+c_3x^2+c_4x+c_5.\tag8$$
Eliminating $x$ between $(6)$ and $(8)$ yields the septic
$$y^7+d_1y^6+d_2y^5+d_3y^4+d_4y^3+d_5y^2+d_6y+d_7=0.\tag9$$
The five unknowns $c_i$ allow us to solve the system
$$d_1 = d_3 = d_5 =0$$
$$2d_2^2=7d_4$$
$$d_2^3=49d_6$$
The septic roots $x,y$ are then related by
$$y=x^5+c_1x^4+c_2x^3+c_3x^2+c_4x+c_5=2\sqrt{-a}\;\cos\left(-\tfrac{2\pi\,k}{7}+\tfrac{1}{7}\,\arccos\big(\tfrac{-b}{2\sqrt{-a^7}}\big)\right)\tag{10}$$

> **III. Questions:**

1. If $F(x)=0$ is a solvable equation, will the coefficients $c_i$ of the Tschirnhausen transformation ***turn out to be radicals***? (I'm of the opinion they are.)
2. For $p=5$, it seems the degree of the $c_i$'s minimal polynomial are quadratics. For $p=7$, are the $c_i$ roots of ***cubics***?